# Why the jsp apply struts2 always display attribute id invalid for tag url according to TLD?

Tags: jsp, struts2, tags, jsp-tags, tld

```
<s:url id = "indexEN" namespace="/" action = "locale" >
  <s:param name = "request_locale" >en</s:param>
</s:url>
    
<s:url var = "indexES" namespace="/" action = "locale" >
  <s:param name = "request_locale" >es</s:param>
</s:url>
        
<s:a href="%{indexEN}" >English</s:a>
      
<s:a href="%{indexES}" >Spanish</s:a>
      
<s:a href="%{indexFR}" >France</s:a>
```

PLease tell me the solution for this problem  .Thank you .

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post pictures of text (or links to pictures of text).](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank for remind using code instead of image but i tried to put the code many times , it always shows the  incorrect format.

Comment: It might be helpful to others if you show a screenshot or text of the error

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use an attribute that doesn't exist on the `<s:url>` tag.

As per [the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/url-tag.html):

> NOTE: The id attribute is deprecated in Struts 2.1.x, and has been replaced by the var attribute.

Comment: Thank for the respond . But is it still available for some struts 2.1 elements using id ? like form tags ?

Comment: @Dannyme It's available on the tags that support it. The tag documentation lists the properties available for each tag.